# Object.create() read-only name property

Tags: javascript

I'm using `Object.create` and the returned object has a read-only `name` property which corresponds to its `prototype`'s type.

```js
var o = Object.create(Object);
o.name = "foo";
console.log(o.name); // "Object"
```

Why does this happen? Where is this documented?

Comment: Probably because you're passing in the object constructor, which is also an object, and has a name property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.create` expects a prototype. By supplying a constructor function as your prototype, you've made `o` an instance of `Function`. `o` is a function that inherits from the `Object` constructor function.

The `name` property of a function is always fixed after creation, so it does not change.